# Path-width and chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring

How would I prove that the chromatic number of a graph $G$ is smaller than or equal to the path-width of $G$ + 1? or $\chi(G) \leq pw(G) + 1$

Comment: It's the other way around - the chromatic number is at most the pathwidth (+ 1).

Comment: @daniello is there any proof of this? Update: I have just realized that you're Dr. Daniel Lokshtanov. I'm a huge advocate of your work and contribution to the theoretical computer science community :)

Comment: *blush*. This should cover all you need: http://www.ii.uib.no/~pinar/chordal.pdf